# How does the length of a double open-ended tube affect its frequency?

Tags: frequency, length

I am attempting to build a trumpet, and need to calculate the lengths of the piping for it. I have attempted to find information on this online, but have been unable to find something that can help me to understand it. I am asking this question on this platform because the results are often more personalised to the specific question being asked. I need to calculate the length to add to a tube to decrease its frequency by $x$ amount, so the concise question would be as such:

When $z$ is the original frequency produced by a double open ended tube, what length, $l$, should be added to it to decrease its frequency by $x$ Hz.

Thanks in advance for the help! (pls - if my question is flawed please tell me)

Comment: a minor flaw, since you asked: $z$ has dimensions of $[T]^{-1}$, and $x$ does not: it's a dimensionless number.